# OpenTok SDK crash Bad Access after disconnecting from a video call

Tags: ios, iphone, opentok

I'm currently using `OpenTok` SDK version 2.6.0 and I am successfully able to create, publish, and subscribe to a session. When I try to dismiss the view controller, if any other subscriber is on the session, I receive an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1, address=0x18` error. I've tried enabling zombies and guard malloc, but I still can't locate the deallocated address in memory that is receiving the selector.

Comment: Can you share code from your view controller? Its not really feasible to help spot the dangling pointer without that.

Comment: @Ankur I feel like it has to be a cleanup issue. The documentation for iOS doesn't seem to provide enough comprehensive coverage about what needs to be explicitly deallocated when you disconnect from a session. unfortunately I think the the session, publisher, and subscriber delegate methods alone would be too long for a single post